# programmatically open search view

Tags: vba, outlook

I am looking for a way to open a search view in outlook for a specified criteria programmatically. I saw other questions such as [VBA Search in Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21549938/vba-search-in-outlook), but they are about retrieving search results programmatically.

I am essentially looking for the same functionality as the Ribbon option Message/Editing/Related:

When I open a message by double-clicking on a message and then click on "Messages in this Conversation"
[image]

The list view changes to

[image]

I would like to be able to do the same thing using a VBA Macro but without opening the message and with a different search criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible ways to show search results in Outlook:

1. The `AdvancedSearch` method of the Application class from the Outlook object model allows to perform a search in multiple folders in Outlook. The key benefits of using the `AdvancedSearch` method in Outlook are:

   - The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the `AdvancedSearch` method runs it automatically in the background.
   - Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The Restrict and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular Items collection (see the Items property of the Folder class in Outlook).
   - Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208216%28v=office.12%29) article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the `Store` class).
   - Finally, you can stop the search process at any moment using the Stop method of the Search class.

   Admittedly, the `Search` class allows you to save the results of searching in a search folder (actually, it doesn’t contain any items, only references to items from the scope folders). You just need to call the `Save` method on the `Search` object in the `AdvanvedSearchComplete` event handler.
2. Customize the current view of the Folder or Explorer objects in Outlook. The [CurrentView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864212(v=office.15).aspx) property returns an instance of the `View` class. See [HowTo: Use the View.XML property to filter Outlook items](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2009/03/13/outlook-items-filter-programmatically/) for more information.

```
 Dim sFilter As String
 Dim CurrentExplorer As Outlook.Explorer = Nothing
 Dim CurrentView As Outlook.View = Nothing
 Dim CurrentXML As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
 Dim CurrentFilterNodes, CurrentViewNodes As XmlNodeList
 Dim CurrentFilterNode, CurrentParentNode As XmlNode

 If TextBox1.Text.Length > 0 Then
     If rbtSubject.Checked Then
        sFilter = "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject LIKE '%" + _
        TextBox1.Text.Trim + "%'"
    Else
        sFilter = "urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription LIKE '%" + _
        TextBox1.Text.Trim + "%'"
    End If

    CurrentExplorer = TryCast(ExplorerObj, Outlook.Explorer)
    If (CurrentExplorer IsNot Nothing) Then
        CurrentView = CurrentExplorer.CurrentView
        If (CurrentView IsNot Nothing) Then
            Try
                CurrentXML.LoadXml(CurrentView.XML)
                CurrentFilterNodes = _
                    CurrentXML.GetElementsByTagName("filter")
                If CurrentFilterNodes.Count > 0 Then
                    For y As Integer = 0 _
                        To CurrentFilterNodes.Count - 1
                        CurrentFilterNode = CurrentFilterNodes(y)
                        If CurrentFilterNode.HasChildNodes Then
                            For i As Integer = _
                            CurrentFilterNode.ChildNodes.Count - 1 _
                                To 0 Step -1
                                CurrentFilterNode.RemoveChild( _
                                    CurrentFilterNode.ChildNodes(i))
                            Next
                        End If
                    Next
                    CurrentFilterNode = CurrentFilterNodes(0)
                    CurrentFilterNode.AppendChild( _
                        CurrentXML.CreateTextNode(sFilter))
                Else
                    CurrentViewNodes = CurrentXML. _
                        GetElementsByTagName("view")
                    If CurrentViewNodes IsNot Nothing Then
                        CurrentParentNode = CurrentViewNodes(0)
                        CurrentFilterNode = CurrentXML. _
                            CreateElement("filter")
                        CurrentParentNode.AppendChild( _
                            CurrentFilterNode)
                        CurrentFilterNode.AppendChild( _
                            CurrentXML.CreateTextNode(sFilter))
                    End If
                End If
                CurrentView.XML = CurrentXML.InnerXml
                CurrentView.Apply()
            Finally
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(CurrentView)
            End Try
        End If
    End If
End If
```

Comment: The Outlook object model is the same for VBA and VB.NET.

Comment: True, but lacks Try Catch Finally.

Comment: _I think OP may recognize helpful pieces of code_ -- You could have written this in C# or Python with the same hope. Also, you are using .NET classes which are not available in VBA, [as someone has already discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51602735/xmldocument-in-outlook-vba?noredirect=1&lq=1). It's unfortunate, because the first half of your answer provides some valuable information.

Comment: I have accepted this answer as I was finally able to adapt it for use with VBA (that someone that @ZevSpitz refers to is me :)). I do believe it was much easier for me to make progress with an example in VB.NET, rather then Python.