# Fetching email addresses with email domain cell value

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, outlook

I fetch email addresses from my Outlook account.

Now I am trying to fetch only specific email address from inbox e.g. Gmail.com that returns gmail addresses only.

I modified the code where I used array to store the addresses temporarily and then compare to string. After altering the code it returns nothing (not even errors).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub GetInboxItems()

Dim ol As outlook.Application
Dim ns As outlook.Namespace
Dim fol As outlook.Folder
Dim I As Object
Dim mi As outlook.MailItem
Dim N As Long
Dim val As String
Dim MyArray() As String, MyString As String, J As Variant, K As Integer

Dim MyAs As Variant
Dim Awo As Variant

MyString = Worksheets("Inbox").Range("D1")
MyArray = Split(MyString, ";")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ol = New outlook.Application
Set ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set fol = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

'Dim inputSheet As Worksheet
'Dim aCellOnInputSheet As Range
'Dim inputDateCell As Range
'Dim userSheetName As String

'Set cod = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Inbox")
'Set aCellOnInputSheet = cod.Range("D1")
'userSheetName = aCellOnInputSheet.Value

Range("A3", Range("A3").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Clear

N = 2
For Each I In fol.Items
    If I.Class = olMail Then
        Set mi = I
        
        N = N + 1
        If mi.SenderEmailType = "EX" Then
        
            MyAs = Array(mi.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress)
        
            For Each Awo In MyAs
                If InStr(MyString, Awo) > 0 Then
                    Cells(N, 1).Value = mi.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress             
                    Cells(N, 2).Value = mi.SenderName
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        '    Cells(N, 1).Value = mi.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress  
        '   Cells(N, 2).Value = mi.SenderName
                  
        Else
            MyAs = Array(mi.SenderEmailAddress)
                       
            For Each Awo In MyAs
                If InStr(MyString, Awo) > 0 Then          
                    Cells(N, 1).Value = mi.SenderEmailAddress
                    Cells(N, 2).Value = mi.SenderName 
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next   
        End If
    End If
Next I

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Fetching all email addresses will be problematic. I don't want to expose any email domains other than the defined ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minimal changes to manipulating the row n and switching the variables in `Instr` should be sufficient.

This also shows how to drop the array if one domain.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub GetInboxItems_SingleDomain()

' Early binding - reference to Microsoft Outlook XX.X Object Library required
Dim ol As Outlook.Application
Dim ns As Outlook.Namespace
Dim fol As Outlook.Folder

Dim folItm As Object
Dim mi As Outlook.MailItem
Dim n As Long

Dim myString As String
Dim myAddress As String

myString = Worksheets("Inbox").Range("D1")  ' gmail.com
'Debug.Print myString

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ol = New Outlook.Application
Set ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set fol = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

Range("A3", Range("A3").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Clear

n = 3

' If slow, limit the number of items in the loop
' e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21549938/vba-search-in-outlook
' strFilter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:fromemail" & Chr(34) & " like '%" & myString & "'"

For Each folItm In fol.Items

    If folItm.Class = olMail Then
    
        Set mi = folItm
        
        If mi.SenderEmailType = "EX" Then
            myAddress = mi.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
        Else
            myAddress = mi.SenderEmailAddress
        End If
        'Debug.Print myAddress
        
        'The bigger text on the left
        ' In general, not necessarily here, keep in mind case sensitivity
        If InStr(LCase(myAddress), LCase(myString)) > 0 Then
            Cells(n, 1).Value = myAddress
            Cells(n, 2).Value = mi.SenderName
            n = n + 1
        End If
        
    End If
    
Next folItm

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Debug.Print "Done."

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks dude it helped for sure was wondering why my code fetched slowly, can you explain me how sql will help me to fetch code faster ?

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/a/27350173/1571407 demonstrates how to restrict the items being processed to the ones you want, without checking each item in the folder.